# Using rbind to merge all columns in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have the following data frame

```
> mydata
X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6
1   1   1   1   1   1
1   0   0   0   0   1
1   1   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   1   1   0
1   1   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   0   1   0
1   1   0   1   1   0
```

I would like to merge all the columns from this dataframe. I can accomplish this by specifying all the columns like this.

```
rbind(mydata$X1,ydata$X2,ydata$X3,ydata$X4,ydata$X5,ydata$X6)
```

What is the best way to merge all the columns in a data frame without having to specify each column? I tried

```
bind(mydata)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `stack(mydata)[1]` or even just `data.frame(x = unlist(mydata))`

Comment: This works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tidyr`'s gather does exactly that:

```
tidyr::gather(mydata)
```

If you then want to get rid of the "key" column, `dplyr::select(mydata, value)` will do the trick (or simply, `mydata$value` if you don't want to keep it as a dataframe)

Comment: The idea is not to have to list the name of each column in the data frame.

Comment: This is very close to what I want. With `tidyr::gather()` the data is still split by columns, but now the data is summarized and the colnames become rownames. With `rbind()`, all I get is 0s and 1s, which is what I want.

Comment: Great! I'll use mydata$value. Thanks so much!